# Error while using webpack -p

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to write code with reacts (JSX) and transformes it with webpack (using babel). I've changed part of my "package.json" file to this:

```
"scripts": {
"production": "webpack -p"
}
```

and I'm running npm run production on command line and this is what i get:

```
> react-fundamentals@1.0.0 production D:\Nave\MyProjects\ReactJs\React-Fundamentals
> webpack -p

webpack 1.13.0
Usage: https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html

Options:
  --help, -h, -?
  --config
  --context
  --entry
  --module-bind
  --module-bind-post
  --module-bind-pre
  --output-path
  --output-file
  --output-chunk-file
  --output-named-chunk-file
  --output-source-map-file
  --output-public-path
  --output-jsonp-function
  --output-pathinfo
  --output-library
  --output-library-target
  --records-input-path
  --records-output-path
  --records-path
  --define
  --target
  --cache                                                                                           [default: true]
  --watch, -w
  --watch which closes when stdin ends
  --watch-aggregate-timeout
  --watch-poll
  --hot
  --debug
  --devtool
  --progress
  --resolve-alias
  --resolve-loader-alias
  --optimize-max-chunks
  --optimize-min-chunk-size
  --optimize-minimize
  --optimize-occurence-order
  --optimize-dedupe
  --prefetch
  --provide
  --labeled-modules
  --plugin
  --bail
  --profile
  -d                                    shortcut for --debug --devtool sourcemap --output-pathinfo
  -p                                    shortcut for --optimize-minimize
  --json, -j
  --colors, -c
  --sort-modules-by
  --sort-chunks-by
  --sort-assets-by
  --hide-modules
  --display-exclude
  --display-modules
  --display-chunks
  --display-error-details
  --display-origins
  --display-cached
  --display-cached-assets
  --display-reasons, --verbose, -v

Output filename not configured.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "production"
npm ERR! node v0.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! react-fundamentals@1.0.0 production: `webpack -p`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294967295
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-fundamentals@1.0.0 production script 'webpack -p'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the react-fundamentals package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack -p
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls react-fundamentals
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Nave\MyProjects\ReactJs\React-Fundamentals\npm-debug.log
```

Does anybody know why?
this is my "web.config.js" file:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

Comment: Rename `web.config.js` to `webpack.config.js`

Answer (score 1):

Webpack looks for a filename webpack.config.js by default. You can rename yours to that or change the script to

webpack -p web.config.js